# Rails: Uncaught ReferenceError: ShopifyApp is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have a Shopify app built on Rails. Getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ShopifyApp is not defined

In reference to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
    ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({
      title: "Groupie",
      icon: "<%= asset_path('favicon.ico') %>"
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm using the [shopify_app gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app). I've looked around for a while and can't figure out how to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your controller inherits from AuthenticatedController:

```
class MyController < AuthenticatedController
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).